# Power BI MTD on page calculation with custom calendar

Tags: powerbi, calendar

I have the following issue. In a report I build, I have a custom created financial calendar. In the first page I have a year and week slicer.
In the second page, I want to calculate MTD(Month-To-Date) values for sales etc.
I have created 2 metrics
first_MTD_Date: It is the first date of financial month and
Last_MTD_date: the last day of the selected week, so I am interested to show results between these 2 dates.
THe metrics are working fine and calculate the appropriate periods.

I know how to create metrics for each value to calculate the result, but I am looking for a more global solution, in order to avoid having to add 50 new metrics in my report.

I have tried creating a flag metric that adjusts based on the selected year/week from the slicers, but this will just flag everything :

Example of the flag :
MTD_Flag_Measure =
VAR CurrentDate = MAX('date_dimension'[Date])
RETURN
IF(
CurrentDate >= [first_MTD_Date] && CurrentDate <= [Last_MTD_date],
1,
0
)

Any suggestions?